# How can I round a chrono::Datetime to the nearest second?

Tags: datetime, rust, rust-cargo, rust-chrono

I want to get the current time rounded to the nearest second using the chrono crate but I don't know how to strip or round the result of
`chrono::UTC.now()`.

It doesn't seem like there are any operations to modify an existing [`DateTime](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.6/chrono/struct.DateTime.html).

```
chrono::UTC.now()
```

Returns: `2019-05-22T20:07:59.250194427Z`

I want to get: `2019-05-22T20:07:59.000000000Z`

How would I go about doing that in the most efficient way without breaking up the `DateTime` value into its components and recreating it?

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`round_subsecs` method](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.6/chrono/trait.SubsecRound.html#tymethod.round_subsecs) with `0` as an argument.

```
use chrono::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let utc: DateTime<Utc> = Utc::now().round_subsecs(0);
    println!("{}", utc);
}
```

The result is:

```
2019-05-22 20:50:46 UTC
```

Comment: That `round_subsecs(6)` can be enabled also by `use chrono::{SubsecRound, Utc};`. This functionality is useful with the Postgres types `TIMESTAMPTZ` having 6 digits instead of the usual `chrono` type `DateTime<Utc>` with 9 digits causing e.g. `assert_eq!(...)` to fail.